# Ubuntu 23.4 MySQL Workbench New Schemas Creation is Disabled

Tags: mysql-workbench

Hey guys please help me my ubuntu 23.4 mysql workbench schemas creating panel is not working, just see my workbench problem screenshot you understand my problem guys.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKP9L.png)

Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: This is an issue with mysql workbench only, nothing to do with mysql server

Comment: Bro you know, how to fix this problem?

Comment: No, we don't understand your problem. It does not appear to be connected to software development, however.